# Please explain me the meaning of String.class, Boolean.class, etc?

Tags: java

I am new to java environment and today while studying jtable I came across Boolean.class, Integer.class, etc which I didn't understood!

I tried to google them but didn't found any explanatory material!
Please, explain me the meaning of these terms and their use!
Thank You!

Comment: Probably every possible case is explained here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html
The second paragraph called **The .class Syntax** is about  `.class`.

Comment: Hint: What file is your code stored in? What's that file called when it's compiled?

Answer (score 2):

Java has a feature called reflection built-in. This means that you can not only *use* classes and other types, you can also *inspect* them to see what members they define, what superclass they have, etc. Every class and interface `T` hass a static member variable `class` of type `Class<T>` which is a reference to an object which describes the class. To get an array of all methods defined by the class `String` for example, you can use `String.class.getDeclaredMethods()`. Note that the class `String` itself does not have a method `getDeclaredMethods()`.

Answer (score 1):

Java has primitive types and reference types. The difference is explained elsewhere.
Some API methods (say, from reflection package) accept only reference types. To pass primitive values, reference counterparts of primitive types are used, like  Boolean, Integer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's special kind of literal called a class literal, formed by taking a type name and appending ".class"; for example, String.class. This refers to the object (of type Class) that represents the type itself.

It means, you can access static class member variables and methods using String.class

It's mentioned in [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
Class fsd {
 String    
Fullstackdeveloper;

 String role; 
}

Public static void main (){ 
fsd fsdref=new fsd();


// fsd fsdref=new fsd();
```

Story has been started.

After creation of this class obj. This class point to fsd.class this jvm understandable syntax.

//meaning that

fsdref point to fsd.class we can say directly call object.

Actually after compilation
.class are generated.

Whan we are creating obj
That obj is holding  .Class
Belong to that particular. Class.

.class syntax invented by sunmicro system not oracle .sun sys company takeover oracle.